# Error in discord.py with .flattern() when removed nothing else works

Tags: python, discord.py

`discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'async_generator' object has no attribute 'flatten'`

This is the error I recieve and when I removed that it does not work either, I also tried to remove the await from there but it also didn't work and internet does not provide answer to that. Anyone know how to fix that?

code:

```
@commands.has_role("⚔️ | Administrator")
async def giveaway(ctx):
    giveaway_questions = ['Na ktorym kanale powinien byc giveaway?', 'Nagroda?',
                          'Jak dlugo ma potrwac (w sekundach)?', ]
    giveaway_answers = []

        return m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel
    for question in giveaway_questions:
        await ctx.send(question)
        try:
            message = await bot.wait_for('message', timeout=30.0, check=check)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await ctx.send(
                'Nie odpowiedziales na pytania, sesja wygasla wpisz ponownie komende aby zaczac giveaway')
            return
        else:
            giveaway_answers.append(message.content)
    try:
        c_id = int(giveaway_answers[0][2:-1])
    except:
        await ctx.send(f'Zapomniales wpisac kanalu! format jaki powienien byc to: {ctx.channel.mention}')
        return

    channel = bot.get_channel(c_id)
    prize = str(giveaway_answers[1])
    time = int(giveaway_answers[2])

    await ctx.send(
        f'giveaway na {prize} zaraz sie zacznie.\nidz na {channel.mention}, aby zobaczyc! giveaway zakonczy sie za {time} sekund.')

    # Giveaway embed message
    give = discord.Embed(color=0x2ecc71)
    give.set_author(name=f'GIVEAWAY', icon_url='http://site21346.web1.titanaxe.com/img/logo.png')
    give.add_field(name=f'Nagroda: {prize}!',
                   value=f'Daj reakcje  aby wejsc!\n Konczy sie za {round(time / 60, 2)} minut!', inline=False)
    end = datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=time)
    give.set_footer(text=f'Konkurs konczy sie {end.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M")} UTC!')
    my_message = await channel.send(embed=give)

    # Reacts to the message
    await my_message.add_reaction("")
    await asyncio.sleep(time)

    new_message = await channel.fetch_message(my_message.id)

    # Picks a winner
    users = await new_message.reactions[0].users().flatten()
    users.pop(users.index(bot.user))
    winner = random.choice(users)
```

Comment: You can use list comprehension instead.

Comment: @3nws AttributeError: 'async_generator' object has no attribute 'flatten' now I get that error

Comment: because you are not supposed to call a function named `flatten`. It was removed. Don't use it. Use a list comprehension.